# Integrating in polar differs from simple integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have same line in orthogonal and polar coordinates, it is `Cos[t]` in first quadrant. But when I integrate those, result differs and I dont understand why:

```
1/2 Integrate[t^2 + Cos[t]^2, {t, 0, Pi/ 2}] // N
Integrate[Cos[x], {x, 0, Pi /2}] // N
```

First gives `1.03866` and second `1`.

Please, help

Comment: Missing a Jacobian? This is a math question, not a Mathematica one...

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, can you, please, show what you mean? When integrating first expression to my understanding it is just sum of `length * delta_phi`. What first expression should look like?

Comment: upvoting first comment is not helpful, correct expression needed

Comment: The correct expression is $A = {1\over2}\int r^2\,d\theta$, not $A = {1\over2}\int r^2\,dt$. I expect you knew that already, but maybe you don't. The comment was hinting that your code doesn't convert $d\theta$ to ${d\theta\over dt}\,dt$. It omits the Jacobian $d\theta/dt$

Comment: by the way, help should be on first place, and bureaucracy on second :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way that let's *Mathematica* figure out everything except how line integrals relate to area via Green's theorem.

```
With[{dA = TransformedField[
    "Cartesian" -> "Polar", (x*Dt[y] - y*Dt[x])/2, {x, y} -> {r, θ}]},
 Block[{r, θ},
  {r, θ} = CoordinateTransform["Cartesian" -> "Polar", {t, Cos[t]}];
  Integrate[dA /. Dt[t] -> 1, {t, Pi/2, 0}]
  ]]
(*  1  *)
```

Alternative, based on $A = \int y\,dx$ (clockwise-oriented boundary)):

```
With[{dA = TransformedField[
    "Cartesian" -> "Polar", y*Dt[x], {x, y} -> {r, θ}]},
 Block[{r, θ},
  {r, θ} = CoordinateTransform["Cartesian" -> "Polar", {t, Cos[t]}];
  Integrate[dA /. Dt[t] -> 1, {t, 0, Pi/2}]
  ]]
(*  1  *)
```

Comment: many thanks, I start understanding my mistake)